# How can I find out if a number is prime or not without using division or modulus in Java?

Tags: java, primes

This is my current code, but it uses division (I'm not allowed to for this task). How can I rewrite this code without using the `/` or `%` operators?

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 31;
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if ((num - (num / i) * i) == 0)
                c++;
        }
        if (c == 0)
            System.out.println("prime");
        else
            System.out.println("not prime");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a rather strange constraint. Is it homework? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: yes its a question from requirement..and i am also surprised that how to write it..

Comment: You can find primes using only addition with the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @thatotherguy: you beat me by one second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with nested loops (semi-pseudocode):

```
int x ;
//check if x is a multiple of any two factors < x
for (int i1 = 2 ; i1 < x ; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = i1 ; i2 < x ; i2++) {
        prod = i1 * i2 ;
        if (prod > x) break ;
        if (prod == x) return "x is not prime" ;
    }
}
return "x is prime" ;
```

This should be reasonably efficient, though for big numbers you'd want to improve it.  One check you could do: `if (i1 == i2 && prod > x) return "x is prime"`  That would eliminate a lot of iterations.

Comment: I just noticed my algorithm will not detect primes 2 and 3, only primes > 4.  So you'd need to have a special case to catch 2 and 3.  I guess you could start i1 at 1, and i2 at i1 + 1, to catch these cases.  Using 1 as an operand looking for primes is kind of BS, but the algorithm can't consider x itself as an operand, so it wouldn't fail that way.

Answer (score 1):

Starting the loop at 2 since that is the first prime:

```
        for (int i=2; i <=100; i++) {
            BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(""+i);
            if (bi.isProbablePrime(9999)) {
                System.out.println("Prime: " + i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I just found for c# and I think it should work:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Write prime numbers between 0 and 100.
    //
    Console.WriteLine("--- Primes between 0 and 100 ---");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        bool prime = PrimeTool.IsPrime(i);
        if (prime)
        {
        Console.Write("Prime: ");
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    //
    // Write prime numbers between 10000 and 10100
    //
    Console.WriteLine("--- Primes between 10000 and 10100 ---");
    for (int i = 10000; i < 10100; i++)
    {
        if (PrimeTool.IsPrime(i))
        {
        Console.Write("Prime: ");
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work then you can atleast develop the list of primes between 0 and 100,000 and then check if the number is part of that list